# How to check if script runs from the correct git root folder?

Tags: git

I have a bash script which needs to be run by the user from the root folder of a specific git repository.

I have found information of how I can check if I am in the root folder of the git.
But is there a way to in the script check that it has been run from the root folder of the *correct* git, and not some other git?

Users of this script usually tends to rename the git when cloning so I cannot check the root folder name.

E.g. `git clone https://git-server.com/gitname someothergitname`

Comment: have you tried checking the remote URL? with git remote -v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute `git config --get remote.origin.url` and check if it is the desired repository or not.

Comment: I ended up using this combined with the info in the comment from @ankidaemon. So my final command reads: `git config --get remote.\`git remote\`.url`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to verify that you are in the root of a local copy of `https://git-server.com/gitname`

My approach would be to check the current origin and compare it against the right one

```
#!/bin/bash

expected_origin=https://git-server.com/gitname

# I use 2>&1 to avoid having STDERR printed to the console
current_origin=`git remote get-url origin 2>&1`

if [ "$expected_origin" != "$current_origin" ]; then
  echo - local origin does not match $expected_origin
  echo FAIL
  exit 1
else
  echo OK!
  exit 0
fi
```

**But there's more to it**

If you were in the right repo, but not in its root folder, the above would still pass the test. You still need to check if you're in the root folder of the local copy using:

```
 git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

And comparing that path againts `pwd`, so the script would be

```
expected_origin=https://git-server.com/gitname
current_origin=`git remote get-url origin 2>&1`;

if [ "$expected_origin" != "$current_origin" ]; then
  echo - local origin does not match $expected_origin
  echo FAIL
  exit 1
else 
  echo - local origin matches expected $expected_origin

  current_folder=`pwd`
  repo_root=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>&1`;

  if [ "$current_folder" != "$repo_root" ];then
    echo - BUT this is not the root folder of this repo!!!
    echo FAIL
    exit 1
  fi
  echo OK
  exit 0
fi
```

Now, why hardcode the remote repo if we can pass it as an argument:

```
#!/bin/bash


function check_origin() {
    expected_origin="$1"
    ... the snippet above ...
}

check_origin "$1"
```

So you could run `./check_origin.sh https://git-server.com/gitname && next_task` which means `next_task` will not be called if the first verification fails.

**Caveat** You'd still need to consider the case in which one of your teammates has the right repo and is on the right folder, but he gloned using `ssh` whereas you're checking using `https`.

**Useless bonus track**

You might want to check if there's a `.git` folder and a `.git/config` file inside. If there was, you could get the origin with cat/tr/cut

```
remote_config=`cat .git/config \
   | tr '\n[\t' ' \n|' \
   | grep 'remote "origin"' \
   | tr '\t' '|' \
   | cut -d' ' -f 5`
```

But this approach is useless, because creating such a file, and filling it with the right contents won't turn the current folder into a local copy.